# st_3dshortestline equivalent in Python 3

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, spatial-analyst

I have two geopandas Dataframes with 3D geometry. I could transform it in any other data type it could be more easy to use.
I would like to know if there is something similar to the **st_3dshortestline** PostGIS function in any Python 3 library, so I do not need to upload to the DDBB all the data.
I tried with Shaperly but I can not find the way for the 3D distance

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The short answer would be to write you own, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727961/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-in-3-d-space

Comment: Thank you @JohnPowell, this way took a really long time instead of st_3dshortestline